# How do I disable the location in gnome-maps

Tags: gnome, geolocation, gnome-maps

How do I disable the location bubble in gnome-maps? I'm using i3 and don't have most of the gnome-settings packages installed, but it seems like [even if you disable location services in gnome, the blue bubble still appears](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/geoclue/geoclue/-/issues/111).

I've tried `sudo sed -i s/true/false/g /etc/geoclue/geoclue.conf` so that gnome-maps doesn't have access to geoclue, but geoclue still starts up and reports a location. I've even tried `chmod 000 /usr/libexec/geoclue` with `killall -9 /usr/libexec/geoclue` and the location still appears.

Is there a gconf setting that lets me disable location entirely in gnome-maps? I'm on a desktop machine in my apartment. It's not going to move. I really don't need a dot to tell me where I am.

[image: Screenshot of Gnome-maps]

Comment: What is `gsettings get org.gnome.system.location enabled`? Maybe it is based on your internet connection? (gitlab.freedesktop.org/geoclue/geoclue/-/wikis/home/). Try using dconf editor>/org/gnome/system/location/ or disable the above schema.

Comment: @kortewegdevries `org.gnome.system.location` is set to `false` However, I restarted gnome-maps and it appears I no longer have a location. I believe it's likely due to disabling execution on the geoclue executable.

Answer (score 1):

Running the command `sudo systemctl mask geoclue.service` in Terminal works for me.